# Ubuntu 22.04 Server Periodic Read Only After fstrim

Tags: ssd, read-only

Running a Dell 7625 server (AMD Epyc, 2 x A30 GPU) for small/medium local research projects.

We swapped out the original disks for 8TB Samsung EVO 870s, with one running the OS.

Every week when fstrim runs its cycle the disk goes read only and it can only be recovered by a hard restart. fsck does nothing and then tells us everything is fine once the ss

This is getting very irritating for my admin people and of course the users. Should we disable fstrim completely and only run it manually when some had physical access?

We have tried to isolate the exact point in the log file where the process fails (we replicated the problem by manually starting fstrim).

Disks are brand new (although that often means nothing), and we tried rotating to an alternative disk and get the same pattern.

fstrim is recommended for SSDs to preserve the life of the disk, but the cost of downtime is way more than the $500 for a new disk and everything is synced so a dead disk is less dramatic than constantly having to physically restart the server each week.

I guess the questions are:

Can we just turn fstrim off?
Is this a symptom of a deeper hardware problem we have to fix (I am not convinced it is the disks as we rotated them, different batch numbers different suppliers); we also rotated the physical disk locations.
We like having space on the OS disk, but we can change that, is having an large OS disk inherently problematic? I had not read anything suggesting this to be the case, but this was one theory we had.

Any suggestions appreciated, apologies in advance if anything here breaks the norms of questions, my first time to ask, happy to provide logs etc as needed.

Comment: What happens when you try to `sudo monut -o remount,rw /` ? What do you see in `dmesg` when `fstrim` fails?